# why Ubuntu 15.04 is using old binaries?

Tags: 15.04, binary

I just noticed that Ubuntu 15.04 is using bsd version of `column` command and its very old i.e. its from 2004. But on arch linux the `column` command is of util-linux is updated on 2014.
So I have two questions: why Ubuntu 15.04 (debian jessie, both being latest release) is giving the old version binaries?

Is there any way to update these kind of core utils?

Comment: File a bug report/feature request. Probably no one needs the newer version.

Comment: @muru I need the latest version of column

Comment: @edwardtorvalds then file a bug report. What good is posting here going to do?

Comment: @muru just a reason why debian is keeping core utils outdated

Comment: @mikewhatever your link does explains why debian is keeping very very old (2004 is 10 years old) core utils outdated

Comment: You're looking at it the wrong way: Why should they update a package that no one is complaining about? Consider this: packages depending on `bsdmainutils` for `column` or any other programs which get shifted would need to be changed as well. Since nobody's complaining, there's no point to taking on a what could be potentially a massive undertaking. `coreutils` is a separate package, I see no evidence that it is outdated.

Comment: @muru do you know  away to remove bsdcoreutils and install util-linux in place of it? since util-linux has the latest version of column and other binaries

Comment: @edwardtorvalds you can download the `util-linux` package from [Arch Linux](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/util-linux/) and extract `column` from it. Removing `bsdmainutils` will cause `man-db` to be removed - whether that's a bad thing depends on how often you use man pages.

Comment: @muru you mean i will not be able to see the man pages at all?

Comment: You'll have to install `man` yourself too.

Answer (score 1):

As @muru said

> ...
>   you can download the util-linux package from Arch Linux and extract
>   column from it.
>   ...

Download the latest version [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/util-linux/) and extract the archive in a temporary folder.

```
tar xf util-linux-2.26.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz -C /tmp/util-linux-2.26.1
```

And copy the content of `/tmp/util-linux-2.26.1/usr/` into `/usr/local`

```
cp -R /tmp/util-linux-2.26.1/usr/* /usr/local
```

Test with, eg.:

```
% column --version                                          
column von util-linux 2.26.1
```

---

I had a problem with that, but the error can be ignored.

```
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'
tar: Ignoring unknown extended header keyword 'SCHILY.fflags'
```

Comment: so you are showing method to replace on `coloumn` command?

Comment: @edwardtorvalds Do you think that's a bad idea?

Comment: I mean you are extracting util-linux, so it will replace all the commands right? and you are just backing up only column command. (backing up command is not bad idea)

Comment: No, I replace `column`.

Comment: @A.B. I'd put it in `/usr/local/bin`, thus keeping both `column`s around.

Comment: @muru Ok, that's better. Thx.

Comment: it will be better if you can show the method all updating all the core binaries

Comment: answer improved